# how to track particular advertisement fragment in video streaming using dot net?

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming

hi i am new to video streaming. Is it possible to trace the timestamp of a particular advertisement fragment in live video streaming? Is there any tool to achieve it? If yes, how to integrate that tool with dot net application?

Can anyone suggest me anything to achieve it ASAP?

Answer (score 0):

Detectors (analysis components) can be written in C++

You could detect commercials via few tools, but doesn't look simple.

http://spench.net/drupal/book/export/html/24

To integrate it with .NET app, it depends on how the tool exposes its features, if you are lucky to get an API, wonderful. If its a console app, you could integrate it easily with C#.